# Foreign key constraint fails but referenced row exists

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I'm running MySQL 5.7.21 on Amazon RDS.

I know [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20024916/mysql-error-1452-23000-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row) [has been](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13891879/error-1452-23000-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-f) [asked a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253459/mysql-error-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fa) [thousand](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/65963/getting-sql-error-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constr) [times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17648179/sqlstate23000-integrity-constraint-violation-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-chi), but I'm getting the issue on a scenario I wouldn't expect, so please read through before downvoting or marking as duplicate.

- I'm not restoring the database, just running single `INSERT` queries, so is not a matter of ordering.
- The referenced row does exist on the table; me and my colleagues had it triple checked.
- As one might expect, disabling the FK checks with `SET foreign_key_checks = 0` does make the query work.
- I've seen this happening because of different table charsets, but in this case, both use `utf8mb4`. Also both have collation set to `utf8mb4_general_ci`.
- This is happening in a production environment, so dropping the tables and recreating them is something I would like to avoid.

Some additional information:

- The FK constraint was created **AFTER** the original tables were already populated.

Here is the relevant portion of the current DDL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `VehicleTickets` (
  `id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `vehiclePlate` char(7) NOT NULL,
  `organizationId` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `createdAt` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updatedAt` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'OPEN',
  `description` text NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `ticketInfo` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `externalId` varchar(100) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (json_unquote(json_extract(`ticketInfo`,'$.externalId'))) VIRTUAL,
  `value` decimal(10,2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (json_unquote(json_extract(`ticketInfo`,'$.value'))) VIRTUAL,
  `issuedAt` timestamp GENERATED ALWAYS AS (json_unquote(json_extract(`ticketInfo`,'$.issuedAt'))) VIRTUAL NOT NULL,
  `expiresAt` timestamp GENERATED ALWAYS AS (json_unquote(json_extract(`ticketInfo`,'$.expiresAt'))) VIRTUAL NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `VehicleTickets_externalId_unq_idx` (`externalId`,`organizationId`),
  KEY `VehicleTickets_vehiclePlate_idx` (`vehiclePlate`),
  KEY `VehicleTickets_organizationId_idx` (`organizationId`),
  KEY `VehicleTickets_issuedAt_idx` (`createdAt`),
  KEY `VehicleTickets_expiresAt_idx` (`expiresAt`),
  CONSTRAINT `VehicleTickets_Organizations_fk` 
      FOREIGN KEY (`organizationId`) REFERENCES `Organizations` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

CREATE TABLE `Organizations` (
  `id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `taxPayerId` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `businessName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'TESTING',
  `createdAt` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updatedAt` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `activatedAt` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `assetConfiguration` json DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

When I run:

```sql
select * from VehicleTickets where organizationId not in (
    select id from Organizations
);
```

I get an empty result set.

However, if I run a query like this:

```sql
 insert into `VehicleTickets` (
  `id`,
  `createdAt`,
  `organizationId`,
  `ticketInfo`,
  `vehiclePlate`
 )
    values (
      '... application generated id',
      '... current date ',
      'cjlchoksi01r8nfks3f51kht8', -- DOES EXIST on Organizations
      '{ ... some JSON payload }',
      '... vehicle plate'
    )
```

This produces the following error:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`VehicleTickets`, CONSTRAINT `VehicleTickets_Organizations_fk`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`organizationId`) REFERENCES `Organizations` (`id`))

Additionally, it gives me:

> ```
> "errno": 1452,
> "sqlState": "23000",
> ```

I've read through several threads regarding this issue, but couldn't find a similar case.

Comment: Have you been able to recreate the issue in the test environment as well?

Comment: I tested on MySQL 5.7.21 and it works. Have you checked if the Organizations.id has any whitespace or strange unicode characters? I can make my test return a 1452 error if I put an extra space in: `set Organizations.id = ' cjlchoksi01r8nfks3f51kht8'` and then try to reference it with the same string, but without the space.

Comment: @DhruvSaxena yes, I happens in my development environment as well.

Comment: @BillKarwin I can try checking for invisible unicode characters, but this would be highly unlikely because these IDs are generated using the same lib I use in other parts of the database and the FKs do work there. Nevertheless, I'll check on this. Thank's a lot.

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos A somewhat crude suggestion, but if the issue gets recreated in development, then I think @BillKarwin's suggestion can be put to use in the following way: (1) [Drop foreign key constraint from the table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/838354/2298301) (i.e. not the column, just the FK constraint); (2) Run the `INSERT INTO VehicleTickets....` query; (3) Try [recreating the foreign key constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10028214/2298301). If it still fails, then there's perhaps a good chance of there being a mismatch of data, data-type or `NULL`ability of the column.

Comment: Hi @HenriqueBarcelos, was just wondering if anything good turned out of this problem?

Comment: Sorry... Unfortunately the priorities shifted a little bit, so I just removed the FK for now.

Comment: Thanks @HenriqueBarcelos. Was just curious about learning what may have caused the error - that's all.

Comment: having the same issue at the moment, any luck with a solution?